# Differential 1-form & 2-form with 4 variables and are identified with 3 function-coefficient

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

I am working on a problem that requires me to compute curl(V) div(V) where V: R4 -> R3, (coordinates are (t,x,y,z) - where x,y,z are time dependent variable) and basis of V =[Vx Vy Vz].

I know I can get curl(V) by taking differential of 1-form and div(V) by taking differential of 2-form.

In this case, is 1-form can be written as Vxdx + Vydy + Vzdz or

Vxdx + Vxdt + Vydy + Vydt + Vzdz + Vzdt?

Similarly, is 2-form can be written as Vxdy ∧ dz + Vydz ∧ dx + Vzdx ∧ dy or

Vxdy ∧ dz + Vxdy ∧ dt+ Vxdt ∧ dz + Vydz ∧ dx + Vydz ∧ dt + Vydz ∧ dt + Vzdx ∧ dy + Vzdt ∧ dy +Vzdx ∧ dt??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis of the vector space of differential $k$-forms in $n$-dimensions consists of all elements of the form:
$$
dx_{i_1} \wedge dx_{i_2} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_{i_k}
$$
where $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k \leq n$. Thus, a generic differential $k$-form in $n$-dimensions can be written as
$$
\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k \leq n} a_{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_k} dx_{i_1} \wedge dx_{i_2} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_{i_k}
$$
where the $a_{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_k}$ are real valued functions of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

That said, my guess is that, in your case, they're asking you to calculate the div, grad, and curl as you usually would in $3$-dimensions. You'll get an answer that depends on time, but which won't involve $dt$. Unless you are doing very advanced math, curl is only defined as an operation which takes (possibly time-dependent) vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to (possibly time-dependent) vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So, in your case, I think they want the first of the two expressions you wrote, but I can't be sure without more context.

Comment: Well as a matter of fact that I need to show that curl(E) + ∂B/∂t = 0, given a relation, F = −Exdt ∧ dx − Eydt ∧ dy − Ezdt ∧ dz + Bxdy ∧ dz + Bydz ∧ dx + Bzdx ∧ dy. I suspect that I need some sort of 2-form that involves dt. Any suggestion upon this?

Comment: That $F$ is known as the field strength tensor. The equations $\text{curl}(E) + \partial B/ \partial t$ and $\text{div}(B) = 0$ are equivalent to requiring that $dF = 0$. Do you know how to compute $dF$?  Also, have they told you that it should be the case that $dF = 0$? I can think of a few ways this problem might be given.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want to consider the exactly the $2$-form you wrote in your comment:
$$\omega = (E_x\,dx+E_y\,dy+E_z\,dz)\wedge dt + (B_x\,dy\wedge dz + B_y\, dz\wedge dx+ B_z\,dx\wedge dy).$$